# Using scrapy built-in selector on local HTML files

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I have some local HTML files and need to extract some elements from it. I am used to writing Scrapy and extract elements using its buit-in selectors with `xpath` and `css` and `.extract()` and `.extract_first()`.

Is there a library that can do this?

I have checked `BeautifulSoup` and `lxml` but their syntax are different from `Scrapy`.

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
sample_file = "../raw_html_text/sample.html"

with open(sample_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    page = f.read()
    html_object = # convert string to html or something
    print(html_object.css("h2 ::text").extract_first())
```

Comment: see my answer -- you can use beautiful soup if you want, but you can also just import the Selector class and pass it a string. Selector(text=string). This is what i do when parsing data in Selenium projects since selenium doesn't have great parsing tools I import the Selector class and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually import scrapy selectors in other projects since I like them so much. Just import the Selector class and pass it a string and it will work just like in Scrapy.

```
from scrapy import Selector

sample_file = "../raw_html_text/sample.html"

with open(sample_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    page = f.read()
    data = Selector(text=str(page))
    title = data.css('h2::text').get()
    # used to be data.css('h2::text').extract_first()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you specifically mentioned `BeautifulSoup` having a different syntax than `scrapy`, but it's definitely the right tool for this job, and it indeed has a method for passing a CSS selector.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_file = "../raw_html_text/sample.html"

with open(sample_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as f:
    page = f.read()
    html_object = BeautifulSoup(page)
    print(html_object.select("h2")[0].text)
    # or print(html_object.select("div.container")[0].text) for div class="container", etc.
```

FWIW, accessing output is very easy as well. The `select` method returns a list of matching `BeautifulSoup` objects. Each object has a `.text` attribute.

Comment: Does not answer OPs question. He did mention beautiful soup but stated he wanted to use similar syntax to Scrapy. So the right answer would be to import the scrapy selector class.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/), which is what Scrapy uses underneath.

Comment: The simple way is using Parsel in a Colab from GDrive :)